# jQuery check if asp.net page is validated

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, validation, .net-4.5

I am populating a asp.NET drop down list in client side, then on clientClick of submit button on page, I am emptying this dropdownlist after puting selected value into a hidden field.

Now because I am validating page, sometime I get validation summary e.g. this is not filled, that is not filled etc and my drop down list becomes empty.

Now I want to make sure that values stay there if validation summary appears, I tried it by checking .is(:visible) but validation summary comes up after my function is being called, now I can use timeout but what if it goes to page validation again before emptying my drop down list.

Comment: Looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228214/calling-callback-method-for-asp-net-validators

Comment: @JNF Thanks, but I am not sure what that answer is doing, it's not even explained properly as if it's using a plugin or something :(

Comment: jQuery validation happens in js and not on the server, so I don't get why validation would break what you did with the DropDownList.